# How to select a dropdown value by classname in Selenium WebDriver using Java

Tags: java, html, selenium, dropdownbox

I am new to selenium , currently I am working in it. I want to select a value from the drop down. The ul class="ns-dropdown" and the option is many in that am trying to select and load Australian Dollar page.

Here is the Html tag:

```
<ul class="ns-dropdown">
<li class="ns-option><a class="c36 noUnderline">USD</a></li>
<li class="ns-option><a class="c36 noUnderline">AUD</a></li>
<li class="ns-option><a class="c36 noUnderline">NZD</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is the code I tried

```
WebElement dropDownListBox = driver.findElement(By.className("ul.ns-dropdown")); 
Select clickThis = new Select(dropDownListBox);
clickThis.selectByValue("Australian Dollar");
```

But this not worked.

Please suggest me some ways to set the drop down value.

Thank You!

Comment: WebElement dropDownListBox = driver.findElement(By.className("ul.ns-dropdown"));
Select clickThis = new Select(dropDownListBox);clickThis.selectByValue("AUD"); But this not worked for me.

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida How to give the Xpath inside the double quotes ?

Comment: @BalamuruganV You should check the [documentation](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)

Answer (score 0):

The [Select](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html) class is meant to be used to be used with `<select>` tags rather than `<ul>` tags, so I imagine that you have been receiving an UnexpectedTagNameException when you try to instantiate `clickThis`?

For your scenario, you should first identify the parent `<ul>` tag using something like:

```
// Very similar to what you first tried!
WebElement dropDownListBox = driver.findElement(By.className("ns-dropdown"));`
```

As the child `<li>` tags you are trying to work with contain their own individual `<a>` tags, you can use the `By.linkText()` locator to find and click the currency option you require like so:

```
WebElement currency = dropDownListBox.findElement(By.linkText("Australian Dollar"));
currency.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

`Select` class is working only on `<select>` tags. In your case you need to open the dropdown to make the options visible and then click on the option you need

```
driver.findElement(By.className("ns-dropdown")).click(); // open the dropdown
driver.findElement(By.linkText("AUD")).click(); // choose Australian Dollar
```

If you have timing issues you can add explicit wait

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

driver.findElement(By.className("ns-dropdown")).click(); // open the dropdown
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.ilinkText("AUD"))).click(); // wait for the option to be visible before clicking on it.
```